# Return values from array based on indices of common values in two other arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, python-2.7, numpy

```
import numpy as np

a=np.random.randint(0,200,100)#rand int array
b1=np.random.randint(0,100,50)
b2=b1**3
c=[]
```

I have a problem I think should be easy but can't find solution, I want to find the matching values in two arrays, then use the indices of one of these to find values in another array

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b1)):
         if b1[j]==a[i]:
             c.append(b2[j])

c=np.asarray(c)
```

Clearly the above method does work, but it's very slow, and this is just an example, in the work I'm actually do *a,b1,b2* are all over 10,000 elements.

Any faster solutions?

Comment: *Any faster solutions?* [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is better suited for this

Comment: @BhargavRao I thinks also stack could be used for short codes ;)

Comment: I agree @Kasra but codereview is the better site

Comment: @BhargavRao Yeah,sure!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`np.in1d(b1, a)` returns a boolean array indicating whether each element of `b1` is found in `a`.

If you wanted to get the values in `b2` which corresponded to the indices of common values in `a` and `b1`, you could use the boolean array to index `b2`:

```
b2[np.in1d(b1, a)]
```

Using this function should be a lot faster as the `for` loops are pushed down to the level of NumPy's internal routines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.intersect1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) to get the intersection between 1d arrays.***Note* that when you can find the intersection then you don't need the indices or use them to find themselves again**!!!

```
>>> a=np.random.randint(0,200,100)
>>> b1=np.random.randint(0,100,50)
>>> 
>>> np.intersect1d(b1,a)
array([ 3,  9, 17, 19, 22, 23, 37, 53, 55, 58, 67, 85, 93, 94])
```

You may note that using `intersection` is a more efficient way as for `a[np.in1d(a, b1)]` in addition of calling `in1d` function python is forced to do an extra indexing,for better understanding see the following benchmark  :

```
import numpy as np
s1="""
import numpy as np
a=np.random.randint(0,200,100)
b1=np.random.randint(0,100,50)
np.intersect1d(b1,a)
"""
s2="""
import numpy as np
a=np.random.randint(0,200,100)
b1=np.random.randint(0,100,50)
a[np.in1d(a, b1)]
    """


print ' first: ' ,timeit(stmt=s1, number=100000)
print 'second : ',timeit(stmt=s2, number=100000)
```

Result:

```
 first:  3.69082999229
second :  7.77609300613
```

Comment: This only gives the intersection not the indices.

Comment: @ajcr It shouldn't produce same type as the OP's result! i just do what OP wants to do with the loops that is finding the intersection!

Comment: @Kasra: I'm not sure the timings are particularly relevant here as the two methods do different things and produce different results (as noted in my previous comment).

Comment: @ajcr Yeah, OP just wants the intersection and i gave it to him! ;)

Comment: I still think you are missing the second part of the question: "I want to find the matching values in two arrays, then use the indices of one of these to find values in **another** array"

Comment: @Kasra: but the OP doesn't *just* want the intersecting values, he specifically mentions getting the indices of the intersecting values.

Comment: @DTing but yes OP says *to find values in another array* so whats is the need for that in the earth? when we have those elements already! if OP was saying i want to remove them or ...  i could offer a way but now i think there is no need to do that!

Comment: I can think of a few. I'm guessing there is a typo in the original question. `c.append(b2[j])` should be the last line in the for loop. This would pretty much indicate the OP is trying to look up a value in B2 that is mapped by index to B1.

Comment: Yes it's b2 values I'm looking for